# Kubernetes-Helm change host value to my app

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have an application that is currently running in to my cluster that was installed using a helm chart.

On the `values.yaml` file from my app there is a host specified as `xxx.dev.xxx.com` I would like to change this to `xxx.prod.xxx.com`

I already tried replacing the value and running helm upgrade to the new value but this creates the following pod `cm-acme-http-solver-xxxx` and my changes are not applied. How can I change my host value?

Also what should I do if I would like to have two copies from my chart on as development and the other one as production?

Comment: How did you originally install the chart?  What `helm upgrade` command are you using?  Can you get a small separate cluster for developer use?

Comment: I didn't install the chart originally it was installed by someone else. Unfortunately no, the dev has to be in the same cluster in a separate name space.

Comment: If you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve] that would be very helpful.  Helm has several different ways to provide settings and the actual setting name in `values.yaml` is controlled by the chart author; so beyond the generic advice to use `helm upgrade` with updated values it's hard to say much more with the current question.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was because I was using the same secret for both apps. I had to create a new secret for the other environment and this fixed the issue.